# Why my code works on online compilers but not on code editors

Tags: python

Why is my code getting stuck in the while loop? I am not able to understand why it's happening. This code is running as usual on online code checkers and compilers like Thorny. But while running it on code editor it goes into an infinite while loop. There is some bug which I am not able to remove. Please resolve my problem.

```
import random

WIN_SCORE = 100
DICE_FACES = 6

Position_of_snakes = {17: 7, 54: 34, 62: 19, 98: 79}
Position_of_ladders = {3: 38, 24: 33, 42: 93, 72: 84}


def starting_title():
    print("###### Welcome to Snake & Ladder Game ######")
    print("###### Lets us Start ######")


def players_name():
    player1_name = None
    while not player1_name:
        player1_name = input("Please enter Player 1 name: ")
    player2_name = None
    while not player2_name:
        player2_name = input("Please enter Player 2 name: ")
    return player1_name, player2_name


def roll_the_dice():
    dice_value = random.randint(1, DICE_FACES)
    return dice_value


def snake_and_ladder(player_name, current_position, value_of_dice):
    previous_position = current_position
    current_position = current_position + value_of_dice

    if current_position > WIN_SCORE:
        return previous_position

    if current_position in Position_of_snakes:
        final_position = Position_of_snakes.get(current_position)
    elif current_position in Position_of_ladders:
        final_position = Position_of_ladders.get(current_position)
    else:
        final_position = current_position
    return final_position


def win_check(player_name, position):
    if WIN_SCORE == position:
        print(f"Congratulations!!! {player_name} won the Game")


def game_start():
    starting_title()

    player1_position = 0
    player2_position = 0

    player1_name, player2_name = players_name()
    while True:
        player_input_1 = input("Enter 'roll' to Roll the Dice").lower()
        dice_value = roll_the_dice()
        player1_position = snake_and_ladder(player1_name, player1_position, dice_value)
        win_check(player1_name, player1_position)
        player_input_2 = input("Enter 'roll' to Roll the Dice").lower()
        dice_value = roll_the_dice()
        player2_position = snake_and_ladder(player2_name, player2_position, dice_value)
        win_check(player2_name, player2_position)

game_start()
```

Comment: You can try to debug using Visual Studio Code

Comment: Well, you have an infinite loop, when do you expect it to stop?

Comment: `while True:` is an infinite loop. The only way to get out of it is with a `break` statement, but there isn't one.

Comment: how can I solved it can you please state

Comment: `win_check()` should return `True` or `False` depending on whether the player has won.  Then you can do `if win_check(...): break`

Answer (score 1):

You have while True which is an infinite loop. You need to declare a variable there and get its value updated after every move. You can use your win_check function to return value of condition.

```
while win_check()
```

and in win_check

```
if WIN_SCORE == position:
    print(f"Congratulations!!! {player_name} won the Game")
    return false
else
    return true
```

Comment: `win_check()` is called twice each time through the loop, with different arguments. So you can't use it as the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out of the loop when a player wins. So `win_check()` should return whether the player has won, and you can use that in an `if` statement.

```
def win_check(player_name, position):
    if WIN_SCORE == position:
        print(f"Congratulations!!! {player_name} won the Game")
        return True
    else:
        return False


def game_start():
    starting_title()

    player1_position = 0
    player2_position = 0

    player1_name, player2_name = players_name()
    while True:
        player_input_1 = input("Enter 'roll' to Roll the Dice").lower()
        dice_value = roll_the_dice()
        player1_position = snake_and_ladder(player1_name, player1_position, dice_value)
        if win_check(player1_name, player1_position):
            break
        player_input_2 = input("Enter 'roll' to Roll the Dice").lower()
        dice_value = roll_the_dice()
        player2_position = snake_and_ladder(player2_name, player2_position, dice_value)
        if win_check(player2_name, player2_position):
            break
```

Comment: I tried but the player_input_1 is running again and again

Comment: What is the purpose of `player_input_1`? You never use the variable.

Comment: If the player enters roll the random number will get generated and the game starts

Comment: I just tested it. The loop stopped when a player won the game. Maybe you're not waiting long enough? It takes quite a few rolls.

Comment: That's the purpose of calling `input()`. You never check whether they typed "roll", so they can type anything. I just kept pressing Return.

Comment: I added `print(f"{player_name} is at position {final_position}")` to the `snake_and_ladder()` function, so I could see the progress of the game.

Comment: yah i saw that . It was a silly mistake from me